# Java Apache-POI nullpointer exception on creating a cell in an existing row

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In the following code, I get a java.lang.NullPointerException on the first `row.createCell(0)`.

When I remove the `spreadSheet.getRow(i+1)` and the if-block after it, then replace them with `spreadSheet.createRow(i+1)` it all works.

Sadly doing it that way deletes some existing data in my rows, so I would like to be able to stop this null exception. Can't seem to figure out what is causing it though:

- i is definitely defined
- row is defined or we would create a new row in the if-block
- the cell is newly made with `createCell()` and thus doesn't have to be defined beforehand

I'm not sure what else to try, I'm mostly perplexed by how it does work when I create a new row but doesn't when I grab an existing one.

```
    //Clone template
    System.out.println(workbook.getNameIndex("template"));
    spreadSheet = workbook.cloneSheet(workbook.getNameIndex("template")+1, infoString);

    //Apply data to cells
    for (int i = 0; i < chartData.getItemCount();i++) {
        row = spreadSheet.getRow(i+1);
        if (row == null) {
            spreadSheet.createRow(i+1);
        }

        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(i+1);
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(chartData.getDataItem(i).getXValue());
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(chartData.getDataItem(i).getYValue());   

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't assign the result of `createRow` back to `row`.  Change

```
spreadSheet.createRow(i+1);
```

to

```
row = spreadSheet.createRow(i+1);
```